# jQuery remove all list items from an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I forgot the jQuery command that will clear all list elements from a list. I did a bit of searching, done it a bunch of times before, but just simply forgot the command.

```
$("ul").clear()
$("ul").empty()
```

both didn't seem to accomplish this.. which command is it again?

UPDATE:
Thanks guys, I must have some syntax error on my selector.

Comment: Are you thinking of `$("ul").remove();`?

Comment: $("ul").empty() should work and clear the childrens.

Comment: @Dave Kiss: remove will remove th ul itself.

Comment: ah, maybe `$("ul").children().remove();`

Answer (score 312, accepted):

`$("ul").empty()` works fine. Is there some other error?

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  $('ul').empty()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="click me" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/D5ss8/

Comment: raw js (no jQuery) solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750137/remove-all-li-from-ul

Answer (score 18):

As noted by others, `$('ul').empty()` [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n5ULH/1/), as does:

```
$('ul li').remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n5ULH/).

Answer (score 11):

This should work:

```
$("ul").html('')
```

Comment: That's odd. Works for me in Chrome (version 20.0). http://jsfiddle.net/Ax4xq/
In either case, I actually prefer the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple ul and want to empty specific ul then use id eg:

```
<ul id="randomName">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>


<script>
  $('#randomName').empty();
</script>
```

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  $('#randomName').empty()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="randomName">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="click me" />
```

Answer (score 3):

$("ul").empty() should work and clear the childrens.
you can see it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKFA5/

Answer (score 3):

```
   var ul = document.getElementById("yourElementId");

     while (ul.firstChild)
         ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look your class or id. Perhaps Like This 
$("#resi_result").html(''); This should work:

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you think your answer improves on the existing, accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

An example using [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
<p>Remove LI's from list</p>
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
<p>END</p>

setTimeout(function(){$('ul li').remove();},1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZAd2Y/

Also, [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) [should have worked](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZAd2Y/1/).

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me with minimal code

```
$(my_list).remove('li');
```