# remove all <li> from <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending `li` in a `ul` using the following code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    li = document.createElement('li');

    element = document.createElement("img");
    element.setAttribute("src", path[i]);

    li.appendChild(element);
    root.appendChild(li);
}
```

Now, I want to remove all items from the list on a button click.  This is what I am using, which isn't working:

```
while(root.hasChildNodes()){
    root.removeChild('li');
}
```

The condition is true but the inner line `root.removeChild('li')` doesn't work.  I also tried these options:

```
root.removeChild(root li);
root.removeChild('#listid li');
root.removeChild('ul li');
...
```

Comment: If this is just straight js why the jquery tag?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, why don't you use its benefits?

Adding `<li>` elements:

```
$("<li><img src='"+path[i]+"'></li>").appendTo(root);
```

Removing all `<li>` elements:

```
$(root).empty();
```

Deleting one `<li>` element:

```
$("li:eq(3)",$(root)).remove();
```

And if you are using raw JavaScript, you can use:

```
document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: you can find examples and a complete function list at http://www.jquery.com . try the examples and play with the functions to learn what they do.

Answer (score 45):

You appear to be trying this with raw JavaScript:

```
while( root.firstChild ){
  root.removeChild( root.firstChild );
}
```

jQuery will only slow you down here.

Comment: slow down? is he talking for 10k's of li elements?

Comment: @tpaksu Unnecessary passes through jQuery are *unnecessary*. Here's some eye-candy: http://jsperf.com/listitem-removal

Comment: `root.innerHTML = "";` would be the fastest if you think.

Comment: @tpaksu Some versions of IE don't play along favorably when interacting with the `innerHTML` method in that way. `firstChild` removal works across the board to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I don't know about that. %1 difference of speed is not so important between your way and the innerHTML way. Thanks for the extra infos.

Comment: @tpaksu This was never about the speed. When I said jQuery would slow him down, I wasn't referring to browser perf. I was referring to the absence of any reason to go through jQuery to do a trivial JavaScript task. With regards to `innerHTML`, that too is not so much a perf issue as it is a compat issue. Different browsers (in the past) operated on that member differently.

Comment: doesn't jQuery handle most of the compat issues?

Comment: @tpaksu jQuery handles the compat issues, when you use it. `elem.innerHTML` doesn't use jQuery, `$.html()` does.

Answer (score 36):

```js
document.getElementById("the_ul_ID").innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 9):

What about?

```
    var ul = root;
    ul.innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $(root).empty();
});
```

Comment: thnks i was using id for making list empty but by the variable it is working thnk u so much can u teach me js online

Answer (score 2):

You can how use `replaceChildren()` to accomplish this:

```js
root.replaceChildren();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the elements before removing them as the native DOM methods (most of them anyway) can't be passed in selector strings the same way jQuery's methods can.

```
var lis = root.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = 0, il = lis.length;i<il;i++) {
    root.removeChild(lis[i]);
}
```