# fill a li element from a array remove duplicates and add values if checked:false (on/off button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodelist

the result is my list is getting bigger every time i call this function. i know i am very close to the solve my problem but im getting really nervous these days. Any help or comment will be appreciated.

```
function devicesoff() {
var devices = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='device_']");

for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {

    if (devices[i].checked === false) {

        var ele = devices[i].name;

        var para = document.getElementById("p");
        var list = document.createElement("li");


        var t = document.createTextNode(ele + "\n");

        list.appendChild(t);
        para.appendChild(list);

    }

}
```

Comment: You would have to remove the list added earlier first then append the new ones, Can u post a fiddle to be more specific to help u?

Comment: So, where is the part that removes duplicates?

Comment: Guys is a bit difficult to post a fiddle because i am using Greek characters and words and i have to replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First clear the old devices, then add new ones.

```js
function devicesOff() {
  var devices = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='device_']");
  var para = document.getElementById("p");
  para.innerHTML = ""; // clear old devices first

  // add new ones
  for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
    if (devices[i].checked === false) {
      var ele = devices[i].name;
      var list = document.createElement("li");

      var t = document.createTextNode(ele + "\n");
      list.appendChild(t);
      para.appendChild(list);
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="device_1" name="device_1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="device_2" name="device_2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="device_3" name="device_3" />

<input type="button" value="devicesOff" onclick="devicesOff()" />

<ul id="p">

</ul>
```

Comment: Ok. This is very weird. Probably is the solution. I did the correction to my code, but still i have the same problem. Any alternative for  innerHTML ?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem, or can you show me the HTML ? innerHTML should work.

Comment: <div id="offlist" class="tabcontent" >
                <h3>Devices Off List</h3>               
                    <ul id="p"> </ul>                        
            </div>               i call the function when tabcontent with the specific id is clicked

Comment: <div class="onoffswitch" >
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox"  id="device_engine1 checked  >
                    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="device_engine1" >
                        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                    </label>
                </div>      is sample of the switch button

Comment: @kostasM. There is a `"` missing in your HTML after `id="device_engine1`. Add that and also look for other HTML mistakes.
 
`<div class="onoffswitch" > <input type="checkbox" name="engine1" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="device_engine1" checked > <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="device_engine1" > <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span> <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span> </label> </div>`

Comment: sorry about that.its right, my mistake during transferring the code.

Comment: is any difference if i use your code inside a tabcontent?

Comment: Job done. i replaced para.innerHtml with $(para).empty according to an older  question. Thanks for you help and your time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750137/remove-all-li-from-ul